# Split a list to list of lists in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have a document class

```
public class Document {
    // system
    private String documentId;
    private String documentTitle;
    private Date creationDate;
    private long fileSize;
    private String fileName;
    private String mimeType;
}
```

I have a method to split the list based on the filesize, i want a list of lists in which each list have a documents whose max file size is 1GB combined
For eg: there are 4 documents which has file size of 0.3GB, 0.5GB, 0.9GB, 0.8GB
In the list of lists i want, 1st list should contain 2 documents because the size is 0.8GB and if we add 3rd the file size will be more than 1 GB,
2nd list should contain a document with 0.9 GB and 3rd list should contain a document with 0.8GB

```
public List<List<DocPakDocument>> groupDocuments(List<Document> document) {
    
        /* Group documents based on fileSize i.e. add document to a list, keeping the total fize size less than maxfileSize which is 1GB    */
        
        
        return null;        
    }
```

Comment: looks like a switch case would be useful

Comment: And what difficulty have you run into in implementing what you describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very straight forward way of doing it.  A stream solution is not really called for here.

assume `List<Document> docs` has the documents.

Sort the list of documents based on fileSize

```
docs.sort(Comparator.comparing(Document::getFileSize));
```

Keep adding documents to the current list while the combined size is less than 1GB.  Then change to a new list.

```
long max = 1_000_000_000;

List<List<Document>> lib = new ArrayList<>();
long currentSize = 0;

List<Document> temp =new ArrayList<>();
lib.add(temp);

for (Document d : docs) {
    currentSize += d.getFileSize();
    if (currentSize <= max) {
        temp.add(d);
        continue;
    }
    currentSize = d.getFileSize();
    lib.add(temp = new ArrayList<>());
    temp.add(d);
}

lib.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```